# Test if connection is an error

Tags: php, conditional-statements

I am using [this script here](https://github.com/xPaw/PHP-Minecraft-Query/blob/master/MinecraftQuery.class.php) and it does not always want to connect to the server I set it to. When it doesn't, it'll show an error `"Failed to receive status"`. I'm wondering how can I test to see if this happens and put it into an if statement?

For example:

```
if (isError) return false;
```

Here is the part which checks for the error or not in the script:

```
if( !$Data )
        {
            throw new MinecraftQueryException( "Failed to receive status." );
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [**try ... catch**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) block. But make sure you are logging the exception message. It'll be helpful for future investigation.

```
try
{
    $Query = new MinecraftQuery( );
    // .. do mine craft connection
    $Query->Connect( '...', 25565 );
    print_r( $Query->GetInfo( ) );
} catch(MinecraftQueryException $mqe){
    // log $mq->getMessage() for future investigation
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Would I be able to do this while I'm calling an object? For example, try { echo $cbMain->GetInfo()['Players'] } catch(error) {} Does it HAVE to be inside of the object?

Comment: Yes, Do all your normal operation in try block.

Comment: @DEVS SEE the update. Also see the README.md https://github.com/xPaw/PHP-Minecraft-Query/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to surround the `Connect` call inside a try/catch block in order to catch the exception, and then put the failure code inside the catch block. You can read more about exceptions in the [PHP manual](http://php.net/exceptions):

```
try {
    $query->Connect();
} catch(MinecraftQueryException $exception) {
    return false;
}
```